# Legends of Runeterra (WINE) don't open

Tags: wine, snap

so, im trying to run LoR on Ubuntu 22.04, the problem is, when i try to open, the message "Legends of Runeterra snap is experimental, etc etc etc" and then don't open, anybody knows what this means?

Comment: You've tagged *bug-reporting* which needs to be done on a bug tracker (this isn't a bug tracker).  You can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for details on how to file bug reports.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: @waltinator In spite of having "(WINE)" in the name this is a snap, likely a re-packaged Windows code in a snap but still it doesn't depend on locally installed Wine.

Comment: @Pedro First of all, here are the system requirements: https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/legends-of-runeterra/19195 . Does your system matches or exceeds those requirements (except OS, of course)? If it does and it still doesn't open as it should then unfortunately there's nothing to do except wait for some eventual update from the snap package maintainers. As the message clearly states it's "experimental". Some user report it not opening at all but most only complain about minor issues like textures, etc.

Comment: Not presenting the complete error message hinders those of us who understand error messages from helping. [Edit] your Question, don't Add comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can run legendsofrunterra from terminal emulator to see the command line output.
One possibility is that you need to install dxvk-master.
Try to reinstall LoR snap:

sudo snap remove --purge legendsofruneterra
sudo snap install legendsofruneterra --edge

and then when you have a choice choose dxvk-master before client installation